# Type mismatch error while mapping column headers

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried this code to to map column headers and it works without any errors.The problem is though it is running without errors i am not getting any output.can anyone please help me to fix it..thanks in advance

```
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet, Sh3 As Worksheet
Dim tmp1, tmp2, tmp3
Dim HeadersOne As Range, HeadersTwo As Range
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook, Wb3 As Workbook
Dim hCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
      tmp1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", 1, "Choose file #1", , False)
      If tmp1 = False Then Exit Sub
      Workbooks.Open Filename:=tmp1, ReadOnly:=True
      Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
      Set Sh1 = Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
      tmp2 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", 1, "Choose file #2", , False)
      If tmp2 = False Then Exit Sub
      Workbooks.Open Filename:=tmp2, ReadOnly:=True
      Set Wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
      Set Sh2 = Wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

      tmp3 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", 1, "Choose file #3", , False)
      If tmp3 = False Then Exit Sub
      Workbooks.Open Filename:=tmp3, ReadOnly:=True
      Set Wb3 = ActiveWorkbook
      Set Sh3 = Wb3.Sheets("Sheet3")
  End With

Set HeadersOne = Sh3.Range("A1:A" & Sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each hCell In HeadersOne

    SCol = GetColMatched(Sh1, hCell.Value)
    TCol = GetColMatched(Sh2, hCell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
    LRow = GetLastRowMatched(Sh1, hCell.Value)

    For Iter = 2 To LRow
        Sh2.Cells(Iter, TCol).Value = Sh1.Cells(Iter, SCol).Value
    Next Iter

Next hCell
      Wb1.Close
      Wb2.Close
      Wb3.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function GetLastRowMatched(Sh As Worksheet, Header As String) As Long
ColIndex = Application.Match(Header, Sh.Rows(1), 0)
GetLastRowMatched = Sh.Cells(Rows.Count, ColIndex).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function GetColMatched(Sh As Worksheet, Header As String) As Long
ColIndex = Application.Match(Header, Sh.Rows(1), 0)
GetColMatched = ColIndex
End Function
```

Comment: `GetOpenFileName` returns a string. `Set` is not needed for that. :) See L42's answer below. It should fix at least that error. :)

Comment: yeah, BK201 is right. Removing `Set` will remove the `type mismatch` because you use `Set` to assign `Objects(eg. Range, Sheet, Application, Chart etc.)` to variables which are properly declared. when you assign values such as `Strings`, no need to use set.

Comment: thank you L42 and BK201 for your clear replies..now i get error "object variable notset"and                                      Set Sh1 = tmp1   is getting highlighted...as i am a fresher i dont have a clue about this..please let me know how i can fix it..thanks again

Comment: `Sh1` is dimensioned as a worksheet, so it should be referring to a worksheet. Since `tmp1` is a string, this is going to throw an error. If you want it to refer to `Sheet1` of the most recently opened workbook, change it to `Set Sh1 = Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")`, for example.

Comment: thank you BK201...now my code(updated) is running without any errors but nothing is getting copied...i dont know why is this happening..please help me sort this out..thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is the same code I did yesterday. I had hoped that you were able to explain everything in one go, so that this could have been solved in one post. Anyway... try the following code. Kindly be clearer next time with your request to avoid redundant fixes.

```
Sub ModdedMap()

  Dim Wbk1 As Workbook, Wbk2 As Workbook, Wbk3 As Workbook
  Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet, Sh3 As Worksheet
  Dim tmp1 As String, tmp2 As String, tmp3 As String
  Dim HeadersOne As Range
  Dim hCell As Range

  'Set up all the strings involved.
  tmp1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", 1, "Choose file #1", , False)
  If tmp1 = "False" Then Exit Sub
  tmp2 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", 1, "Choose file #2", , False)
  If tmp2 = "False" Then Exit Sub
  tmp3 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", 1, "Choose file #3", , False)
  If tmp3 = "False" Then Exit Sub

  'Open all the workbooks using the previous strings.
  Set Wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(tmp1)
  Set Wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(tmp2)
  Set Wbk3 = Workbooks.Open(tmp3)

  'Set the target sheets. MODIFY ACCORDINGLY.
  Set Sh1 = Wbk1.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set Sh2 = Wbk2.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set Sh3 = Wbk3.Sheets("Sheet3")

  Set HeadersOne = Sh3.Range("A1:A" & Sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For Each hCell In HeadersOne

      SCol = GetColMatched(Sh1, hCell.Value)
      TCol = GetColMatched(Sh2, hCell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
      LRow = GetLastRowMatched(Sh1, hCell.Value)

      For Iter = 2 To LRow
          Sh2.Cells(Iter, TCol).Value = Sh1.Cells(Iter, SCol).Value
      Next Iter

  Next hCell

  Wbk1.Close
  Wbk2.Close
  Wbk3.Close

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function GetLastRowMatched(Sh As Worksheet, Header As String) As Long
ColIndex = Application.Match(Header, Sh.Rows(1), 0)
GetLastRowMatched = Sh.Cells(Rows.Count, ColIndex).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function GetColMatched(Sh As Worksheet, Header As String) As Long
ColIndex = Application.Match(Header, Sh.Rows(1), 0)
GetColMatched = ColIndex
End Function
```

Let us know if this fixes anything. If it fails, kindly describe your problem ***in detail***. Apparently, the data are in 3 sheets in 3 separate workbooks. Test the above, change the parts where your input is needed, and kindly report the result here.

Comment: thank you BK201 and sorry for not being clear...i tested the code and i am getting a type mismatch error and "If tmp1 = False Then Exit Sub"is getting highlighted...

Comment: @user3172566: Changed `False` to `"False"`. Try it now. :)

Comment: @user3172566 again `tmp1` is variable to contain string. If `GetOpenFilename` is cancelled, `tmp1` is not set. Meaning it is empty. So to check, `If IsEmpty(tmp1) Then Exit` Sub should work or `If tmp1 = "" Then Exit Sub`. If however you declare it as variant then `If tmp1 = False Then Exit Sub` should work.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
tmp1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", 1, "Choose file #1", , False)
```

Add commas `,` since you didn't specify the argument name.
Aslo this returns `String` so no need to use set.

Another way is:

```
tmp1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", FilterIndex:=1, Title:="Choose file #1")
```

Here, you specify the arguments.
Again no need `Set`.